# Как правильно вызвать метод с CancellationToken на языке VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Имеется библиотека, в ней определены методы с непонятными для меня сущностями.
Вот определения методов.

```vb
<AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(<GetAnswer>d__9))>
Public Function GetAnswer(ImageFilePath As String, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
<AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(<GetAnswer>d__10))>
Public Function GetAnswer(Img As Image, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
```

Вопрос, как правильно вызвать метод `GetAnswer` и "с чем едят" `CancellationToken`

```
Dim retval As String = Await rucap.GetAnswer("", ??? )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от правок вопроса, которые полностью меняют его смысл. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его в виде отдельного вопроса, дав ссылку на оригинал . А не превращайте вопрос в пост о поисках решения с добавлением udp по мере продвижения.

Comment: я категорически не согласен с вашими правками!

Comment: Я не вносил правок, я всего лишь откатил вопрос до его первоначальной версии. Тема сущетвенной корректировки вопоса [совсем недавно обсуждалась на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2948/). Предлагаю вам оформить upd-ы в качестве полноценного, цельного, вопроса (с кодом для воспроизведения проблемы), если они еще актуальны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно создать `CancellationTokenSource`, а в качестве аргумента передать значение свойства `Token`. Вызвав метод `Cancel` у source или задав ограничение по времени, вы сможете прервать выполнение операции.

Если прерывание операции вас не интересует, можете просто передать `CancellationToken.None`.

Comment: Не все так просто как оказалось далее, может подскажете как следующую пробле мурешить?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Можете попробовать использовать блокирующее свойство `Result` у возвращаемого `Task`.

Comment: как это сделать если я раньше с этим не работал... я не понимаю то что вы предалагаете сделать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Вы б почитали про async/await, а то нагородите костылей,  потом гадать будете, почему всё зависло или медленно работает. Те функции, которые вас интересуют, возвращают `Task(Of String)` — это не магический объект, с ним можно совершать операции. В частности, у него есть свойство `Result`, которое дожидается окончания асинхронной операции, блокируя текущий поток. `GetAnswer("", CancellationToken.None).Result`, собственно.

Comment: появились новые обстоятельства, они в обновлении.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Ну как, вопрос то в самом верху обозначен вроде... а дополнения внизу самом, почему нельзя вызывать с CancellationToken.None